# How to make a Python generator execution asynchronous?

Tags: python, asynchronous, generator, yield

I have a piece of of code that looks like this:

```
def generator():
    while True:
        result = very_long_computation()
        yield result

def caller():
    g = generator()
    for i in range(n):
        element = next(g)
        another_very_long_computation()
```

Basically, I'd like to overlap the execution of `very_long_computation()` and `another_very_long_computation()` as much as possible.

Is there simple way to make the generator asynchronous? I'd like the generator to start computing the next iteration of the while loop right after `result` has been yielded, so that (ideally) the next `result` is ready to be yielded before the succesive `next()` call in `caller()`.

Comment: FWIW, there's a very interesting video youtube tutorial by David Beazley titled [A Curious Course on Coroutines and Concurrency](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Z_OAlIhXziw) from PyCon 2009 which you would probably find very enlightening.

Comment: I'll check it out, thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no simple way, especially since you've got `very_long_computation` and `another_very_long_computation` instead of `very_slow_io`. Even if you moved `generator` into its own thread, you'd be limited by CPython's global interpreter lock, preventing any performance benefit.

You could move the work into a worker process, but the `multiprocessing` module isn't the drop-in replacement for `threading` it likes to pretend to be. It's full of weird copy semantics, unintuitive restrictions, and platform-dependent behavior, as well as just having a lot of communication overhead.

If you've got I/O along with your computation, it's fairly simple to shove the generator's work into its own thread to at least get some work done during the I/O:

```
from queue import Queue
import threading

def worker(queue, n):
    gen = generator()
    for i in range(n):
        queue.put(next(gen))

def caller():
    queue = Queue()
    worker_thread = threading.Thread(worker, args=(queue, n))
    worker_thread.start()
    for i in range(n):
        element = queue.get()
        another_very_long_computation()
```

Comment: Actually very_long_computation() is about 50% of computation and 50% I/O. Do you think it is possible to overlap with at least the I/O part?